# How to I extract this NativeScript code to re-usable function?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

#### Problem Overview

I am trying to extract some working code from my NativeScript code-behind file, and create a re-usable function from it.

The code in question is actually a plug-in, called [NativeScript Feedback.](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-feedback)

Before I go on, I would like to mention I am very new at NativeScript.

The plug-in demo code was written in TypeScript, and it took me a very long time of trial and error to get it to work in my core application.

Here is the working code:

```
// example-page.js
// +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// | ALCA IT SOLUTIONS - Preferred Blank NativeScript Templates                |
// +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+                                                                       |                              |
// | VIEW MODEL Variables                                                      |
// | To access properties within view-model from XML screen:                   |
// |    -- use double curly brackets {{ }}                                     |
// |       example:  <Label text="{{ username }}" />                           |
// |                 <Button text="tap me" tap="{{ myTapMethod }}"/>           |
// | To access functions OUTSIDE of view model from XML screen:                |
// |    -- omit double curly brackets                                          |
// |       example:  <Button text="tap me" tap="myGenericFunction" />          |                                 |                                                                             
// +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// | 1. IMPORT REQUIRED FILES                                                  |                                                                        |
// +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
const  { app }         = require("tns-core-modules/application");
const  { fromObject }  = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");
var frameModule = require("tns-core-modules/ui/frame");

// Feedback Testing
const  Color  = require("tns-core-modules/color");
const Feedback  = require("nativescript-feedback").Feedback;
const FeedbackType  = require("nativescript-feedback").FeedbackType;
const  FeedbackPosition  = require("nativescript-feedback").FeedbackPosition;
const isIOS  = require ("tns-core-modules/platform");

// +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// | 2. CREATE VIEW MODEL                                                      |                                                                        |
// +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
const model = {

  /* Properties */
  username: "john",
  password: "12345",
  feedback: new Feedback(),
  feedbackPosition: FeedbackPosition,
  feedbackType: FeedbackType,

  /* Methods */
  onNavTap: function(args){
    const navBtn = args.object;
    const page = navBtn.page;
    const btnId = navBtn.id;

    switch(btnId) {
      case "btn-activity":
          //page.frame.navigate("./activity/bloodpressure/bloodpressure");
          break;
      case "btn-programs":
        // code block
          break;
      case "btn-messages":
          // code block
          break;

      case "btn-journal":
          // code block
          break;

      case "btn-community":
          // code block
          break;

    }

    //alert(`${navBtn.id} is the id of the button!`);
    //this.showSuccess();
    this.showError();
    //this.showWarning();
  },

  showSuccess: function() {
    this.feedback.success({
      title: "Successfully shown myself!",
      message: "I'm configured to hide after 2.5 seconds.",
      duration: 2500,
      // type: FeedbackType.Success, // no need to specify when using 'success' instead of 'show'
      onTap: () => {
        console.log("showSuccess tapped");
      }
    });
  },

  showError: function(){
    this.feedback.show({
      title: "Feature Incomplete",
      titleSize: 25.0,
      message: "The Health Conscious feature you are trying to view has not been completed yet. Please check back soon!",
      messageSize: 14.0,
      duration: 5000,
      position: this.feedbackPosition.Bottom,
      type: this.feedbackType.Error,
      onTap: () => {
        console.log("showErrorBottom tapped");
      }
    });
  },

  showWarning: function(){
    this.feedback.show({
      // title: "The warning title",
      message: "This one doesn't have a title, but a very long message so this baby will wrap. Showing off multi-line feedback. Woohoo!",
      duration: 4000,
      position: FeedbackPosition.Top,
      type: FeedbackType.Warning,
      onTap: () => {
        console.log("showWarning tapped");
      }
    });
  }

}

/* Set the binding context */
const bindingContext = fromObject(model);

// +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// | 3. OTHER FUNCTIONS ( Not bound to ViewModel )                             |                                                                        |
// +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
function pageLoaded(args) {
  var page = args.object;
  page.bindingContext = bindingContext;
}

function onDrawerButtonTap(args) {
  const sideDrawer = app.getRootView();
  sideDrawer.showDrawer();
}

// +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// | 4. EXPORT OTHER FUNCTIONS                                                 |                                                                        |
// +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
exports.onDrawerButtonTap = onDrawerButtonTap;
```

As you see, the Feedback plug-in is successfully working in this page.

I have tried to exract it into its own file, and them I tried to "require" it. Nothing worked.

How could I extract this Feedback code into its own file which I could call upon? I would like to be able to call showSuccess, showWarning, showError from ANY page in my app - that would be great. Even better of course, would be to send parameters.

Could you show me how I would put those 3 functions in their own file, please?

I sure would appreciate the help. Thank you.

John

Comment: I'm on mobile or I'd write a sample. Basically you need to create your new js file. Copy over your feedback requires and your functions. Make sure you `export` the functions and then you can require your new file (module) in any other file or just require the functions since you will have declared them as exportable. So your module (new file) might be "feedback-util.js" and then your require to use the module would be a relative path to that file. Assuming you are in the same directory on a new file `const f = require("./feedback-util");` then `f.showSuccess(arg, arg2)` call exported function

Comment: To allow the arguments to be passed you just declare the argument parameters when you write the function. So then when you call that function you provide the values for the arguments

Comment: ok I will try now. Brad, what is the difference between const  { fromObject }  =  and const from Object = ...  I know the brackets mean something different. Ok be back with my code, see if it works!

Comment: Brad I need to accept your answer, please post the text as an "answer" somehow. I don't see a button to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your new js file. Copy over your feedback requires and your functions. Make sure you export the functions and then you can require your new file (module) in any other file or just require the functions since you will have declared them as exportable. So your module (new file) might be "feedback-util.js" and then your require to use the module would be a relative path to that file. Assuming you are in the same directory on a new file `const f = require("./feedback-util");` then `f.showSuccess(arg, arg2)`

To allow the arguments to be passed you just declare the argument parameters when you write the function. So then when you call that function you provide the values for the arguments